# how do i store and get a queue of structure?

Tags: c++, struct, queue, structure

How do I store and get value of structure into a queue where I have 2 values? I wanna queue this few values.

> | 4 , 2 |
>
> | 3, 5 |

Where by 4,2 and 3,5 can be a variable such as

```
primaryQ.push(a, b);
```

My structure:

```
struct primarytemp{
    double process;
    double secondary;
};
```

Here's how I declared my main:

```
int main(){
    queue<primarytemp> primaryQ;
    primaryQ.push(4, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just push a `primarytemp` object into the queue, without modifications to the type:

```
queue<primarytemp> q;

q.push(primarytemp{4., 2.});  // Requires current C++ standard (C++11)

primarytemp p = {3., 5.};
q.push(p);                    // Also  works pre-C++11
```

As has been mentioned by others, you can add a constructor to `primarytemp`, although this means it is no longer an aggregate. This may or may not matter.

```
primarytemp
{
  primarytemp() : process(), secondary() {}
  primarytemp(double process, double secondary) 
  : process(process), secondary(secondary) {}

  double process;
  double secondary; 
};
```

This allows you to say

```
q.push(primarytemp(4., 2.)); // Also works pre-C++11
```

---

To access the element you just pushed, use the `back()` method, which returns reference:

```
std::cout << "process" << q.back().process() << std::endl;
```

You can make a copy of that element too:

```
primarytemp = q.back();
```

The `front()` method allows you to do the same with the first element in the queue.

To remove the element at the front:

```
q.pop();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C++, you could use `pair<double, double>` instead of manually creating a queue.
This is how to declare it and use it:

```
queue< pair<double, double> > primaryQ;
pair<double, double> myPair;
myPair = make_pair(3, 5);

cout << myPair.first;//will print 3, the first element of the couple
cout << mtPair.second//will print 5, the second element of the couple

primaryQ.push(myPair);//push the pair into the queue
```

You can also insert it like this:

```
primaryQ.push( make_pair(3, 5) );
```

Comment: `struct` is better option then `pair` because latter you may want to add third value.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem (not that it is easy to know what the problem is.)

Answer (score 0):

As it is C++ `struct` has constructor, so you could:

```
struct primarytemp
{
    primarytemp(double p, double s) : process(p), secondary(s)
    {}

    double process;
    double secondary;
};
```

And:

```
int main(){
    queue<primarytemp> primaryQ;
    primaryQ.push(primarytemp(4, 2));
}
```

---

Also if you have only two values, you can use `pair<double, double>`, `struct` is good in case you have more data.

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler provides C++11 features you can use `std::queue::emplace(...)` method. Emplace() allows you to create element of queue by forwarding its argument list directly to constructor of queue type. See code below:

```
struct primarytemp
{
    double process;
    double secondary;

    primarytemp(double aProcess, double aSecondary) 
        : process(aProcess), secondary(aSecondary) {}
};

int main()
{
    queue<primarytemp> primaryQ;
    primaryQ.emplace(4.0, 2.0);
}
```